# Python two loop in dataframe for split data

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have multi class model output in list in dataframe.

I am split a list strings and get probabilities. I am putting this to new columns.

I try to do this in one line. Can we do this in one line?

List example:

```
df3["probsL"][5] 
['CLASS_101:0.008794423192739487',
 'CLASS_102:1.0509392450330779E-4',
 'CLASS_103:7.038920884951949E-4',
 'CLASS_104:0.06047835946083069',
 'CLASS_105:0.4600931704044342',
 'CLASS_106:0.0010375826386734843',
 'CLASS_107:0.0010938106570392847',
 'CLASS_108:1.1317161988699809E-4',
 'CLASS_109:0.4266757369041443',
 'CLASS_110:6.553125567734241E-4',
 'CLASS_111:0.0028506366070359945',
 'CLASS_112:3.44081869116053E-4',
 'CLASS_113:0.0020616059191524982',
 'CLASS_114:0.005628892686218023',
 'CLASS_115:0.029364245012402534']

df["probsL"][5][5] 
'CLASS_105:0.4600931704044342'
```

My code

```
for i in range (0,df.shape[0]):
if type(df["MODEL_OUTPUT"][i])==str:
    for l in range (1,len(df["probsL"][i]) + 1 ):
        #print(i,l)
        #print(float(df["probsL"][i][l-1].split(":")[1]))
        df.at[i,l]=float(df["probsL"][i][l-1].split(":")[1])
```